# Missing template after respond_to or redirect_to

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

I have perfectly working method for publishing messages:

```
def new_message
  #adding message to database
  tmp_message = Message.new  
  # Check if user is muted
  if current_user.role == 'muted'
    params[:message] = "пытался что-то сказать, но кляп оказался     сильнее"
  end
  # Check if the message is private
  if recipient = params[:message].match(/@(.+) (.+)/)
    # It is private, send it to the recipient's private channel
    @channel = "/messages/private/#{recipient.captures.first}"
    @message = { :username => current_user.username, :msg =>     recipient.captures.second }
  else
     # It's public, so send it to the public channel
    @channel = "/messages/public"
    @message = { :username => current_user.username, :msg =>     params[:message] }
  end
    tmp_message.channel = @channel
    tmp_message.message_text = params[:message]
    tmp_message.username = current_user.username
    tmp_message.save
  respond_to do |f|
     f.js
  end
end
```

Then, I copyied this method to work with data from database:

```
def get_messages
 for i in 1..Message.count
  tmp_message = Message.find_by_id(i)
  if tmp_message
    if recipient = tmp_message.message_text.match(/@(.+) (.+)/)
    # It is private, send it to the recipient's private channel
    @channel = "/messages/private/#{recipient.captures.first}"
    @message = { :username => tmp_message.username, :msg =>     recipient.captures.second }
    else
    # It's public, so send it to the public channel
        @channel = "/messages/public"
    @message = { :username => tmp_message.username, :msg =>     tmp_message.message_text }
    end
  end
 end
     respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render nothing: true } 
     end
```

end

and called it in "room" method:

```
def room
  redirect_to sign_up_path unless user_signed_in?
  if current_user.email == "madowley@gmail.com"
    current_user.role = "admin"
  end
    @queue = Array.new;
    @queue = queue_list
get_messages
end
```

get_messages.js looks like:

```
// Clear message input
$('#message').val('');

// Send the message
<% publish_to @channel, @message %>
```

I`ve tried to add "format.html" and got "Jump error, missing block (yield)"

Comment: Could you try to to use `render :action => :get_messages` instead of plain `get_messages` and see what happens? It's an action, not a method...

Comment: @RubyRacer still missing template

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to  test your solution. However, I think that the problem lies in the rendering mechanism of what you are trying to do... Also, some stuff that need considering:

- If you want to run methods in your action, you should leave rendering out.
- You should do redirecting in a filter, not on the action flow (see `before_action` below)
- You should state rendering explicitly in each method, unless you wish to have defaults..

To solve this, I think some restructuring of your controller should be in order:

```
before_action :before_room, only: :room

def get_messages
    messages
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js {render :nothing => true}
    end
end

def room
    if current_user.email == "madowley@gmail.com"
        current_user.role = "admin"
    end
    @queue = Array.new;
    @queue = queue_list
    messages
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js {render :nothing => true}
    end
end

private:
def before_room
    redirect_to sign_up_path unless user_signed_in?
end

def messages
    Message.all.each do |message| # different approach, more "Rails" way
        if recipient = message.message_text.match(/@(.+) (.+)/)
        # It is private, send it to the recipient's private channel
            @channel = "/messages/private/#{recipient.captures.first}"
            @message = { :username => message.username, 
                         :msg => recipient.captures.second }
        else
            # It's public, so send it to the public channel
            @channel = "/messages/public"
            @message = { :username => message.username, 
                         :msg => message.message_text }
        end
    end
end
```

As I said, not tested it... Let's hope it's useful.

Comment: Your solution looks great, but  now I`m getting "ActionController::UnknownFormat" error. And can I somehow pass parameters from form to the "messages" method without making a new one?

Comment: Please, can I see the full error message? And the answer to your question, is of course yes, with a variety of ways (strong params, before filter, inline etc)

Comment: @RubyRacerActionController::UnknownFormat
Rails.root: C:/Sites/faye-tutorial
app/controllers/chats_controller.rb:7:in `get_messages'

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25074739/actioncontrollerunknownformat-with-format-js-for-ajax-implementation-rail-4

Comment: I`ve tried to add "format.html" and get this error:Missing template chats/get_messages, application/get_messages

Comment: No, check the chosen answer... If you are using an ajax call, maybe you should explicitly set the format to `js`

Comment: I`m not sure, because I only call this method inside controller and it doesnt take any additional data