# Ruby on Rails change Bootstrap Badge content when Ruby Variable Changes without reloading the whole page again

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

> First of all i am very new to Ruby on Rails and in Ruby ( 3 weeks
>   experience ) and i am coming from Java and JavaFX background.

I have created a small e-commerce website and you can find all the code here -> https://github.com/goxr3plus/Ruby-on-Rails-eCommerce-Website

> An image of the website top section
>   [image]
>
> Description of the problem

So you can see a link named `Basket (0)` where 0 is the number of items inside the basket . This number is a ruby variable and it increases every time the user presses `Add to Basket` for a new item .

---

So what is the problem ? **When the Add to Basket is pressed i don't want to reload all the website in order the text of `Basket (0)` to go `Basket(1)` for example.**

I don't know how to achieve this ... Here is the code of the Rails Controller when a new item is created and added to the basket.

---

**line_items_controller.rb**([Full Code](https://github.com/goxr3plus/Ruby-on-Rails-eCommerce-Website/blob/master/app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb)) ( actually the cart items controller)

```
def create

     /....code code


     //.. Ok so now the basket item counter has increased
     **How i can call some javascript code to refresh the Navigation Bar without reloading the website ?**    

    end
```

Code from Navigation Bar (**_header.html.erb**) ([Full Code](https://github.com/goxr3plus/Ruby-on-Rails-eCommerce-Website/blob/5102d9b7ac87844fdaf1e0815d94adad645e0003/app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb))

```
 <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning" id="total_cart_items_badge"><%= @current_cart.line_items.count %></span>
```

For any more information you need please ask me  . I am searching 2 days now can't find a solution ...

> Random Idea
>
> If i define this function on `application.js` :
>
> ```
> function updateHeaderBar() {
>   $('total_cart_items_badge').text(totalBasketItems)
> }
> ```
>
> how can i call it from the `line_items_controller.rb`?

---

**Finally**

For example in [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) , we can define value change listeners and bindings so everytime the value changes an action is fired ( you can call methods etc ).

Is there something similar on [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) ?

Comment: You are going to need AJAX calls. A simple way would be to create a javascript function for your button and prevent it from doing what it normally does. Then accept a json format in your controller. And at last, update the page using the returned data.

Comment: @RezaKazemirad Let's say i have a `jquery` function inside `application.js` . It detects given SPAN based on it's id and changes it content `$('total_cart_items_badge').text(total)` . How i can call this function from inside Rails Controller. Can i have an example of your solution also . You can add an answer , i will not downvote :)

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question following this amazing tutorial -> https://coderwall.com/p/kqb3xq/rails-4-how-to-partials-ajax-dead-easy

And using this StackOverFlow question - > [ActionController::UnknownFormat with format.js for ajax implementation (Rail 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25074739/actioncontrollerunknownformat-with-format-js-for-ajax-implementation-rail-4)

I am so happy that i will add more to this answer . So basically what i wanted to do is update the text of SPAN whenever the total_items variable changed . So here we go ->

Firstly create a file which has the same name as the method of your controller. For example in my case i am calling it from `create` method of controller because this method is called every time the `Add To Basket` button is pressed.

[image]

As you can see i am just catching the span using it's ID and with embedded Ruby i am changing it's content.

So what about the controller method it self ? The code is below :

```
def create
   //...code code code

    respond_to do |format|
     if @line_item.save!
       format.js
       # below is a second way without creating ``
       # format.js { render :js => "alert('hi')" }
     else
       format.html { render :new , notice: 'Error adding product to basket!' }
     end
   end
end
```